# How to download and install rtl8xxxu driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, proprietary-drivers

I'm using rtl8192cu on various distros and getting slow internet speeds on them, but on bodhi linux, since rtl8xxxu is available and loaded, I'm getting higher speeds.

I'm curious to know if it is possible to download the rtl8xxxu drivers and use them on other distros as well?

lsmod | grep rtl on bodhi linux returns:

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
mac80211              778240  1 rtl8xxxu
```

And I guess that's the reason I have higher speed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My network driver is rtl8192cu and I've just figured out there are some issues with this driver not only for me but many other users.
After digging deeply for hours,I found the following to be helpful for me.

Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

(In my case I didn't need to install linux headers)

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

[Source page](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg --search rtl8xxxu.ko
```

Then use https://wiki.debian.org/apt-src (no idea how that works for Bodhi Linux but it should) to download the sources of whatever package which contains this kernel module. You can now use it everywhere else.

It would be nice to test whether simply downloading the latest firmware for this module fixes your speed issues because I a hunch that's the most probably cause.